# Fabric.js loadFromJSON breaking text into new line in fabric.Textbox, whereas original original textbox shows single line

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I am working on a project using the Fabric.js library to create and manipulate textboxes. In my application, I am using the fabric.Textbox object to create a textbox, it is shown in a single line.

When I create a new canvas and add this textbox to it using the loadFromJSON method, the text is split into multiple lines. However.
I am wondering why the fabric.Textbox object is behaving differently in the two scenarios. Is there any setting or property that I need to adjust to make the textbox behave consistently in both cases?
Any help or insights on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]